# Difference bw puts with braces() and without braces

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence, puts

What is the difference bw puts("Odin") and puts "Odin"? 
**Context**
`puts "odin" || true` gives different result than `puts("odin") || true`

Answer (score 3):

Ruby understands `puts "odin" || true` as `puts("odin" || true)` which will always output `odin`. It will not evaluate the `|| true` part because `"odin"` is already truthy. And that line will return `nil` because that is the default return value of the `puts` method.

`puts("odin") || true` will output `odin` too but will return `true` because the return value of `puts("odin")` is `nil` and therefore the `|| true` will be evaluated and the `true` will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the priority of evaluation:

- in the first example `"odin" || true`  evaluates to `true` and then is used as an argument to `puts` (which returns `nil`);
- in the second example `puts("odin")` returns `nil` which is then evaluated to `true` in `nil || true` statement;

Answer (score 1):

braces are optional in ruby, or better said: in some cases spaces act as like braces would.

the reason you get two different results is because of where the braces are interpreted, so both the following statements *print "odin" and return nil*:

```rb
puts "odin" || true  
puts("odin" || true)
```

Remember here that strings are **truthy** in ruby, meaning we actually have a **condition inside the puts method**, ie `true || false #=> true`

As for the second example, the condition is no longer passed as a argument to the **puts** method. **puts** returns **nil**, which is **falsey**.

```rb
puts("odin") || true #=> true
```

this means the overall return is `nil || true #=> true`